# mp3 trigger, output to antoher input, no switch

Tags: arduino-uno

I have two Arduinos: one is transferring on its output pin to other Arduino's input_pullup low or high signal depend on servo action (rotating/stop).

I need an action on slave Arduino with dfmini player: actually I need a code with which mp3 sample is triggered on slave Arduino.

servo rotates -output pin goes low = sample is played just once until servo reaches desired position

servo stopped -output pin goes high = sample stops

solving this issue will be really helpful for my project.

here is example code

tnx.

```
***************************************************
  DFPlayer - A Mini MP3 Player For Arduino
  <https://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=1121>

 ***************************************************
  This example shows the basic function of library for DFPlayer.

  Created 2016-12-07
  By [Angelo qiao](Angelo.qiao@dfrobot.com)

  GNU Lesser General Public License.
  See <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/> for details.
  All above must be included in any redistribution
 ****************************************************/

/***********Notice and Trouble shooting***************
  1.Connection and Diagram can be found here
  <https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/DFPlayer_Mini_SKU:DFR0299#Connection_Diagram>
  2.This code is tested on Arduino Uno, Leonardo, Mega boards.
 ****************************************************/

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h"
#define pin 2 // connect to master digital output "pin"  


SoftwareSerial mySoftwareSerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer;
void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value);

void setup()
{
 mySoftwareSerial.begin(9600);
 Serial.begin(115200);
 pinMode(2,INPUT_PULLUP);

 Serial.println();
 Serial.println(F("DFRobot DFPlayer Mini Demo"));
 Serial.println(F("Initializing DFPlayer ... (May take 3~5 seconds)"));

 if (!myDFPlayer.begin(mySoftwareSerial)) {  //Use softwareSerial to communicate with mp3.
   Serial.println(F("Unable to begin:"));
   Serial.println(F("1.Please recheck the connection!"));
   Serial.println(F("2.Please insert the SD card!"));
   while (true);
 }
 Serial.println(F("DFPlayer Mini online."));

 myDFPlayer.volume(15);  //Set volume value. From 0 to 30
}

void loop(){
  if (digitalRead(2)==LOW) myDFPlayer.play(1); // 5 sec mp3 sample, turn on , then debounce or return ?

}

}
```

wiring scheme
[image]

[image]

output cobmination on master arduino
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem in writing the necessary code?

Comment: im newbie, i know little about coding, is it solution complicated ?

Comment: The normal way is to start learnimg coding with tutorials and simple examples from the web. You most likely won't find an example, that exactly fits your goal, but you can use them to learn enough to solve your problem. You can always ask a specific question here and we will try to help you.

Comment: i have searched online , but i cant find any example with direct connection between output and input pins, always button or switch is included.

Comment: For the slave Arduino it is just an input pin. It doesn't know, what is connected to the pin. Thus it is irrelevant, if you connect a button or a second Arduino to that input pin. For the slave these options are the same

Comment: yes, thats true, but stil waiting for possible solution.

Comment: you are going to have a long wait